# HTML Dom Parser does not return expected value

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to get a specific value of the gift, the price in grams of silver in euros, from this site: https://www.gold.de/kurse/silberpreis/,

```
$html = HtmlDomParser::file_get_html('https://www.gold.de/kurse/silberpreis/');

$t = $html->find('span.fw700', 0)->plaintext;
$t = explode(" ",$t);

$t = str_replace("g","",$t[1]);
$silver_price_per_gr = str_replace(",",".",$t);

echo 'silver_price_per_gr: '.$silver_price_per_gr.'<br/>';
error_log('silver_price_per_gr: '.$silver_price_per_gr."\n", 3, "cron.log");
if(floatval($silver_price_per_gr) > 0){
    update_silber_base_price($silver_price_per_gr);
}else{
    echo 'skipped silver_price_per_gr <br/>';
    error_log("skipped silver_price_per_gr\n", 3, "cron.log");
}
```

in the code above, I put the class I wanted, but it doesn't return any value, following the log:

```
Update on: 2022-01-26 19:00:12
gold_price_per_gr: 52.13
silver_price_per_gr: 
skipped silver_price_per_gr
```

below I will leave the Xpath path that I copied from the dom:

```
//*[@id="sb-site"]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/section/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/span
```

the value it would have to return would be 0.68
[image]

Comment: Does `$t` contain a value? If so, what is it? Also, so you know, there are many many spans with the class `fw700`, you might be pulling the wrong one.

Comment: I used $t to separate the string, is that wrong? yes there are several spans with the same class, but I couldn't find the correct one, can you show me the way?

Comment: It's probably not wrong, but I was more curious about what it contains. For instance, if it contains EUR (as mentioned in your previous questions comments), then it's not what you want. Unfortunately, I'm not very familiar with HTML Dom Parser, so couldn't tell you exactly how to navigatee through it.

Comment: One thing that might help, though, is that you want to get the first section with the class of `preistable`, and then the first span that has the class of `fw700`.

Comment: You can't code based on console output. That is built from JS actions as well. Use what you have from the server and build from there. I also would use DomDocument rather than html parser.

Comment: Please use echo and print_r() for arrays for debugging i.e. ``print_r(explode(" ",$t))`` and see where the problem starts

Comment: I gave print(explode) but it didn't return, where do I check?